# UIButton on UIView gave error to open other ViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I’m using UIView and make something like view is overlap on presentView when user click the particular tableview cell with didSelectRowAtIndexPath,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    // Initialize Books View Controller
    mainView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    mainView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor] ;
    [self.view addSubview:mainView];

    viewDisplay=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2,0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    viewDisplay.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.6];
    [self.view addSubview:viewDisplay];

    [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];
    UILabel *purposeLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45, 20, self.view.frame.size.width, 40)];
    NSDictionary *myNames = [data objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    purposeLabel.text=[myNames objectForKey:@"name"];
    purposeLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:18.0];
    purposeLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    [viewDisplay addSubview:purposeLabel];

    UITextView *purposeLabelThree=[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 70, 150, 320)];
    purposeLabelThree.text=[myNames objectForKey:@"description"];
    purposeLabelThree.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:15.0];
    purposeLabelThree.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    purposeLabelThree.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [viewDisplay addSubview:purposeLabelThree];

    UIButton *viewButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    viewButton.frame=CGRectMake(20, 420, 120, 40);
    [viewButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showNewView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [viewButton setTitle:@"OK" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    viewButton.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
    [viewDisplay addSubview: viewButton];

    // Push View Controller onto Navigation Stack
    //    [self.navigationController pushViewController:servicesViewController animated:YES];
}

-(void) showNewView:(id)sender
{    
    [subView removeFromSuperview];
    [viewDisplay removeFromSuperview];
   // [mainView removeFromSuperview];

    BidGenerate *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BidGenerate"];
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:NO completion:nil];
    [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:NO animated:YES];
}
```

and i’m using UIButton on UIView and trying to call the new ViewController but it gave me error

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target .'

I’m also trying to use :-

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main.storyboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

but it gave me error like, Main.storyboard is not present in the NSBundle.

Can anyone please help me to find a way to open a new Viewcontroller through this UIView based UIButton ?

Thanks In Advanced.

Comment: You are trying to present a nil instance of a view controller and that is the reason for the crash. Initialize your view controller properly and everything would work fine.

Comment: Can you elaborate me the things little bit i'm new to iOS development here i'm using mainView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)]; what should i do?

Comment: If you are new to ios then try this: http://www.raywenderlich.com/50310/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-2

Comment: check your viewcontroller's identifier

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see for yourself whether the view controller instance has some value,

```
-(void) showNewView:(id)sender
{    
    [subView removeFromSuperview];
    [viewDisplay removeFromSuperview];
   // [mainView removeFromSuperview];

    BidGenerate *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BidGenerate"];
    NSLog(@"View Controller: %@",controller); 
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:NO completion:nil];
    [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:NO animated:YES];
}
```